# How to display the variation name in Woocommerce Items

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, product

I am trying to make a Ajax popup cart where product will be add dynamically. Everything is working fine except the product variation. when a variable product added to cart its not showing the variation name:

```
<?php 
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) {
        $_product       =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );
        $product_link   = get_permalink( $values['data']->get_id() );
        $title          = $_product->get_title();
        $variations     = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data($values,true);
        echo '<a href="'.$product_link.'">'. $title.'</a>';
        echo $variations;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you just need to use [`WC_Product` method  `get_name()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_name) *(see in the template `cart/minicart.php` [on line 36](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/cart/mini-cart.php#L36))* replacing in your code the line:

```
$title          = $_product->get_title();
```

with:

```
$title          = $_product->get_name();
```

> **Important Note:** In some cases you will need to add the following lines *(depending on what you want to display and where)*:
>
> ```
> // Force displaying variation attributes in the product name (in cart/minicart/checkout)
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_true' );
> // (Optional) Force displaying product variation attributes as separated formatted metadata (in cart/minicart/checkout)
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' );
> ```
>
> *Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*
>
> **To test it**, once added this code to your theme's `functions.php` file, empty the cart first, as cart fragments are cached in mini cart (Ajax).

This time it will show the variation name.