# How to auto copy title into description field for all WooCommerce variation products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

I have lots of variable products and the description field is left blank by default, but I have other plugins which are set to display the Variation Description field on the front end. How can I get my site to copy the variation name (Pink Set No Box, Pink Set With Box, Green Set No Box etc.) into the corresponding variation description field?

As well as doing it for all existing products, it would need to do it for all new products being added as well.

So how can I copy automatically for product variations, the title into description field in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying the variation product name in the variation description, you can assign it to the description dynamically using this very simple hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_description', 'wc_product_variation_get_description_filter', 10, 2 );
function wc_product_variation_get_description_filter( $description, $product ){
    return $product->get_name();
}
```

Or you can also append it to the description using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_description', 'wc_product_variation_get_description_filter', 10, 2 );
function wc_product_variation_get_description_filter( $description, $product ){
    return $description . $product->get_name();
}
```

Or prepend it with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_description', 'wc_product_variation_get_description_filter', 10, 2 );
function wc_product_variation_get_description_filter( $description, $product ){
    return $product->get_name() . $description;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

On some cases when products have been created since a long time, the attributes are not displayed in the product variation name… You will need to add the following line:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_true' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related:

- [How to display the variation name in Woocommerce Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384634/how-to-display-the-variation-name-in-woocommerce-items/57385345#57385345)
- [Remove attribute values from product variation title and show them on separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377644/remove-attribute-values-from-product-variation-title-and-show-them-on-separate-r/47380351#47380351)

Comment: Thanks this is a much better approach - is there a way to get the first option to return only the variation name rather than the product name + variation name? For example at the moment it returns 'Demo Product 1 - Small' rather than just 'Small'.

Comment: @Lyall It's already returning the variation name in my code as $product is the WC_Product_Variation Object… So if you to get it (that happen on some old products), you might need to add some additional code… I will add this code at the end of my question in a short time.

Comment: Ah ok, apologies I didn't realise. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks - I've added that extra line but it's still showing the full product name and the variation title together (I've tried adding the last part before and after the function)

Comment: @Lyall So may be I didn't catch what your problem is… On my side it works perfectly as the method get_name() on a product variation give the variation name. So I  don't understand what is your issue…

Comment: That's no problem - it's probably something that's been introduced by a plugin. However I can get around it (because it's consistent) by using substr($product->get_name(), strrpos($product->get_name(), "-") + 2) to take everything after the join